# PHP to show/hide slideshows depending on page id

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show different slideshows on different pages

I think i need to use an if elseif else PHP loop but cant get the syntax right

Here is my code:

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
 <div class="mobile-header"> <img src="/images/mobile-header.jpg" width="1080" height="1000" alt="Sean Sheehan" /> </div>

<?php  if  ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) )  { soliloquy( 'homepage-dark', 'slug' ); } ?>

<?php else : ?>
        <header id="masthead" class="<?php echo is_singular() && twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail() ? 'site-header featured-image' : 'site-header'; ?>">
```

Whenever I try and add an elseif the code breaks. I tried this to show a different slider on page id 25:

```
 <?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
 <div class="mobile-header"> <img src="/images/mobile-header.jpg" width="1080" height="1000" alt="Sean Sheehan" /> </div>

<?php  if  ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) )  { soliloquy( 'homepage-dark', 'slug' ); } ?>

 <?php   elseif ( is_page(25) ) { 
?>
 <div class="mobile-header"> <img src="/images/mobile-header.jpg" width="1080" height="1000" alt="Sean Sheehan" /> </div>

<?php  if  ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) )  { soliloquy( 'photography-dark', 'slug' ); } ?>

<?php else : ?>

<header id="masthead" class="<?php echo is_singular() && twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail() ? 'site-header featured-image' : 'site-header'; ?>">
```

But this code is not correct.

Comment: Please give more details like how *the code breaks*: what error messages are you seeing?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ':' in /homepages/4/d554888208/htdocs/sean/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen-child/header.php on line 61

Answer (score 0):

The main problems are:

- whilst you can use `{}` or `:` structure for `if` statements, you cannot *mix* them in the same control block ([details](https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) here). Since you started with `if():` you cannot use `elsif() {` in `<?php elseif ( is_page(25) ) {`. You need to use the format `elsif():`, so that line needs to read like so – `<?php   elseif ( is_page(25) ):`
- you need to close the block with `endif;`

So the corrected code (see comments below) should look like:

```
<?php if( is_front_page() ) : ?>
 <div class="mobile-header"> <img src="/images/mobile-header.jpg" width="1080" height="1000" alt="Sean Sheehan" /> </div>

<?php  if  ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) )  { soliloquy( 'homepage-dark', 'slug' ); } ?>

<!-- elseif(): not { -->
<?php   elseif ( is_page(25) ):?>

 <div class="mobile-header"> <img src="/images/mobile-header.jpg" width="1080" height="1000" alt="Sean Sheehan" /> </div>

<?php  if  ( function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) )  { soliloquy( 'photography-dark', 'slug' ); } ?>

<?php else: ?>

<header id="masthead" class="<?php echo is_singular() && twentynineteen_can_show_post_thumbnail() ? 'site-header featured-image' : 'site-header'; ?>">
    <!-- don't forget endif; -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```